# записать дату codigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Есть скрытое поле.

```
<input class="form-control" name="last_edit"  value="<?php echo  date("Y-m-d H:i:s")?>" type="hidden" >
```

Проблема заключается в занесении этих данных в базу в формате timestamp. 
Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
    //1. В контроллере получаете массив POST
    $post_arr = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);

    if(isset($post_arr["last_edit"])) {
    //2. С помощью функции strtotime переводите "текстовую" дату в timestamp
        $last_edit_timestamp = strtotime($post_arr["last_edit"]);
    }
```

Comment: Проблема не в том, что интовое значение после перевода функцией strtotime не записівается в базу, а в том, что мне нужно именно строковое представление(вида 0000-00-00 00:00:00)

Comment: Хм, не очень понимаю ваше уточнение. Где Вам нужно строковое представление? Может Вы имели ввиду как значение timestamp,полученное из БД превратить в строку вида YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS?